# 'Uncaught HttpErrorResponse' Jasmine test failed

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service with a function that search for a brazilian zip code. It's working normally. But it's not my problem.

```
public getAddress(cepAddress: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(`${URL + cepAddress}/json/`).pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                return response;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
```

I have been trying to test the error response, but apparently, i have no error. But when i open the console, i have one error of 'Uncaught HttpErrorResponse'. That crashes my test and not generate any coverage because this. I have tryed to follow the angular documentation, in this [url](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests), including using the asyncError, but without success. The error can be seen here

[image]

I am having success to test the response case, but the error case is being a little difficult to me.

```
const ERRORRESPONSE = new HttpErrorResponse({
  error: 'test 404 error',
  status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found',
  url: 'fakeurl'
});
describe('CadastroService', () => {
  let httpClientSpy;
  let service: CadastroService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['post', 'get']);
    service = new CadastroService(httpClientSpy as any);
    // service = new CadastroService(<any> httpClientSpy);
  });
  it('should test getAddress error', () => {
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(throwError(ERRORRESPONSE));
    service.getAddress('09890430').subscribe((response) => {
      fail('getAddress error expected');
    }), (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      expect(error.status).toEqual(404);
      expect(error.error).toEqual('test 404 error');
    };
  });
});
```

Applications versions

```
"@angular/core": "9.0.6",
"jasmine": "^3.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
```

I have an application with a very similar function and test that are running ok, but this not.
I would like to have the test passed by the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try like this .Let me know if it not works.

```
beforeEach(() => {
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(CadastroService)
      });

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
          providers : [CadastroService]

        });
    });


it('should test getAddress error', () => {
    const ERRORRESPONSE = new HttpErrorResponse({
      error: 'test 404 error',
      status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found',
      url: 'fakeurl'
    });
    service.getAddress('09890430').subscribe((response) => {
      fail('getAddress error expected');
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      expect(error.status).toEqual(404);
      expect(error.error).toEqual('test 404 error');
    });
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${URL + cepAddress}/json/`);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(ERRORRESPONSE);

    httpMock.verify();
  });
```

Comment: Hi man. I have tryed this, but i had to comment var cepAddress to run, but even like that, i had this error -> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[HttpTestingController -> HttpTestingController]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpTestingController!